# Как правильно установить новую версию библиотеки в golang?

Tags: golang, websocket

При импортировании новой версии библиотеки, возникла проблема.
Делаю go get "github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2"
не находит метод WsCombinedKlineServe которого нет на первой версии.
Попробовал сделать go mod init  "github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2",  пишет при компиляции  import cycle not allowed и package main становится красным. Подскажите, как мне такое исправить?  И вообще это нормально что файл go.mod появляется в папке проекта? а вот, когда делаю go mod  init  "github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2" Мейн становится красным.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2"
)

func main() {
    pairs := map[string]string{
        "BTCUSDT": "1m",
        "ETHUSDT": "1m",
    }
    wsKlineHandler := func(event *binance.WsKlineEvent) {
        fmt.Println(event)
    }
    errHandler := func(err error) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    doneC, _, err := binance.WsCombinedKlineServe(pairs, wsKlineHandler, errHandler)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    <-doneC
}
```

Файл go.mod

```
module github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2
go 1.15
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Исправьте ваш вопрос и покажите файлы `go.mod` и `go.sum`. Заодно добавьте текст вашей программы, чтобы можно было попробовать скомпилировать у себя.

Comment: Исправил. Извините, я не знал что надо текст добавить!. А где найти файл go.sum? Просто когда я делаю go mod "***" файл появляется в папке проекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так.

1. Для начала переименуйте ваш модуль. Удалите `go.mod` и инициализируйте его заново командой `go mod init example.org/try/binance`. Вместо `example.org/try/binance` может любое имя, которым вы хотите назвать ваш модуль.

После этой операци `go.mod` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
module example.org/try/binance

go 1.16
```

2. Добавьте библиотеку `go-binance` командой `go get github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2`

В консоли будет что-то вроде

```
go: downloading github.com/adshao/go-binance v2.3.5+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2 v2.3.5
go: downloading github.com/bitly/go-simplejson v0.5.0
go: downloading github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.0
go get: added github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2 v2.3.5
```

а `go.mod` станет таким:

```
module example.org/try/binance

go 1.16

require github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2 v2.3.5 // indirect
```

Заодно рядом с `go.mod` появится файл `go.sum`.

3. После того, как вы добавите `go-binance` в `go.mod` компилятор не будет ругаться на `WsCombinedKlineServe`:

```
PS> go run main.go
&{kline 1648726509274 ETHUSDT {1648726500000 1648726559999 ETHUSDT 1m 793582883 793582911 3404.00000000 3403.99000000 3404.00000000 3403.99000000 4.67000000 29 false 15896.66794500 3.46450000 11793.15800000}}
&{kline 1648726510988 BTCUSDT {1648726500000 1648726559999 BTCUSDT 1m 1310607031 1310607154 47175.82000000 47175.81000000 47175.82000000 47175.81000000 1.28785000 124 false 60755.37448040 0.75719000 35721.05914580}}
&{kline 1648726511632 ETHUSDT {1648726500000 1648726559999 ETHUSDT 1m 793582883 793582915 3404.00000000 3404.00000000 3404.00000000 3403.99000000 5.58290000 33 false 19004.17905400 4.32830000 14733.53320000}}
&{kline 1648726513008 BTCUSDT {1648726500000 1648726559999 BTCUSDT 1m 1310607031 1310607198 47175.82000000 47175.81000000 47175.82000000 47175.81000000 2.33832000 168 false 110312.15603140 1.59922000 75444.51486040}}
exit status 3221225786
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!!!!!) 2 дня не мог справится с этим!!

Comment: Хотел спросить еще кое что. Как мне добавить этот модуль в общий модуль?? Раньше насколько я помню, я просто делал go get  и go mod  и когда я создавал новые проекты, мог воспользоваться этой библиотекой. В данном случае, для каждого проекта мне нужно добавлять вручную все. И еще менеджер не подсказывает методы и поля структур после точки.

Comment: @Alisher если честно, мне непонятен ваш вопрос. "Этот" модуль - это какой? И что такое "общий модуль"?

Comment: Я хотел сказать, что когда я добавляю библиотеку таким способом, менеджер(VS code) не подсказывает методы и поля после точки, приходится все методы и поля вручную прописать.  Раньше когда я добавлял библиотеку и делал go mod init * файл go.mod не появлялся у меня в папке проекта и подсказка работала. Для меня как то странно, что файл go.mod появляется у меня в папке проекта...Такое ощущение, будто я что то делаю не так, но все работает. Благодарю.

Comment: `go mod init` нужно вызывать только один раз за всё время разработки. Все последующие разы вам нужно использовать команду `go mod tidy`. Эта команда обновляет `go.sum` и, при необходимости, `go.mod`. И да, файлы `go.mod` и `go.sum` лежат в корневой папке проекта и VS Code их не прячет.